# I need help to debug

Tags: fetch, http-status-code-404, mern

I need help with a little issue.

My code is running fine, and my object is successfully deleted from both the DOM and the database. However, I'm encountering a 404 error.

I believe my code is continuing to search for the ID after the deletion, which results in the following error message:

```
DeletePost.jsx?t=1691565212108:33 DELETE http://localhost:5000/post/64d33cc79f3fe8ac9a8ee0ba 404 (Not Found).
```

My code :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function DeletePost() {

  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const confirmDelete = window.confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce post ?"); 

    if (!confirmDelete) {
      navigate("/");
      return;
    }

    async function fetchData() { 
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/post/${id}`, {
          method: "DELETE",
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          navigate("/");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  
    fetchData();
  }, [id, navigate,]);
  
  return null; 
}

export default DeletePost;
```

Thank you :)

i'm blocked on a stupid error and i need help